# Port rails 2.X app ActionWebService to Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Has anyone successfully migrated a Rails 2.X ActionWebService implementation to Rails 3? I've tried examples in forked ActionWebService gits without success. I realize REST is blessed. However, I have to support client SOAP calls and don't have access to the client code.

Ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]
Rails 3.0.5

This is the point I'm at.
ArgumentError (ActionWebService is not missing constant Base!):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  app/controllers/home_controller.rb:3:in`'

Comment: Have you tried Ruby 1.8.7 instead?  I'm going to have this same problem at some point. :(